How to fix error: "FAIL: Unable to load driver '\efi\rufus\exfat_x64.efi': [26] Security Violation"
I'm trying to reinstall Windows 10 but the short DST test fails and also it states Unable to load driver '\efi\rufus\exfat_x64.efi': [26] Security Violation.

My laptop is a HP EliteBook 840 G3 1TB HDD

The easiest way is to temporarily disable Secure Boot (if that’s what’s causing the message), if that is acceptable for you. // The driver is supposed to be signed IIRC, so that shouldn’t really be required.

This ^^^ or remake the installation media but do NOT change Rufus defaults (the default being NTFS, not exFAT, and unlike the latter, the NTFS driver is signed). Alternatively use the Official Media Creation Tool or the multi-boot tool Ventoy.

Rufus and UEFI:NTFS dev here, which is where your error comes from.
Unlike the NTFS one, the exFAT driver used in UEFI:NTFS is not Secure Boot signed, and never will be due to Microsoft's arbitrary decision to never ever sign anything that's GPLv3.
This is why you get a Security Violation in a Secure Boot enabled environment if you try to boot a UEFI:NTFS drive using the exFAT driver.
Now, I have to wonder, since you most likely created the drive with Rufus, why you decided to use exFAT over NTFS, when you wouldn't have had that issue with NTFS. Unless, for some weird reason, you really, really need to access the bootable media content under Mac (but then I have to ask why you would need to do so) there really is zero advantage to changing the Rufus defaults and using exFAT over NTFS for creating a Windows installation drive.
At any rate, temporarily disabling Secure Boot to boot a Windows installation media that you created from a trusted source is not the end of the world (it will not magically make your system get malware because you happened to load the unsigned exFAT driver), so you can just do that, and re-enable Secure Boot once Windows has completed the first part of the installation process.
